# Writing cover letter for company

Tags: cover-letter

I'm currently studying IT, it's my second year. I'd like to apply for a job related to business administration in a technology industry I'm greatly interested at. I've never had worked in this technology field before, nor do I have anything to prove I'm fit for business administration. I'd like to refer to my 4 years of high school where I've spent a great amount of time as a volunteer organizing and managing event, leading people and learning about entrepreneurship and business. But that was two years ago. I'm afraid they'll find it irrelevant. I currently work as a developer and I'm not sure how to make these things relevant in the cover letter.

What are the things that I should mention and in what order?

Any tips on how I can prove to them that I am a good fit would be welcomed. I think my technical background for this industry (it's automotive) is only an advantage.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about putting experience down from 2 years ago. That's still quite recent, especially if it helped you build skills that will help with the job you're applying for. I only started taking high school work/volunteering off my resume after I left college and had a couple years of college/work experience to fill out a resume.

Comment: It unfortunately seems like this question would be way too specific to the job you're applying for, you and your experience for us to be able to answer this or for it to be applicable to anyone else. Try to find a decent cover letter template and update it with the appropriate information.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your university. Most have an office that helps students find jobs. It might cover students university wide, or it might be based in your specific department.

They can give guidance on resumes and cover letters. If the company is local they may even be able to give much more tailored advice.